# How to find CurrentPage in HtmlUnit from webclient

Tags: java, htmlunit

When I used HttpUnit, I would invoke `getCurrentPage()` method of HttpUnit to get the current page. How can I do that in HtmlUnit? I tried `webclient.getHomePage()`, but it seem to return wesite of htmlunit.

One suggestion I got is use getPage using previous URL, but that doesn't work for me because I need to refactor a code that is earlier written in a code which makes it impossible reexecute previous request.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the following approach to get HtmlPage object from webclient assuming you already navigaed to a page either by using wc.getPage(url) or submitting a form in previous page or using any other method. Assuming that `wc` is the WebClient object.

```
HtmlPage currentPage = (HtmlPage) wc.getCurrentWindow().getEnclosedPage();
```